# Return Text to Display value from Outlook Hyperlink

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to call a Word.Hyperlink object inside Outlook to access the properties of Hyperlinks embedded in an email, but cannot get a return of the human readable text from the Hyperlink object.

I'm using Word as there is no Outlook.Hyperlink object that I can find (I ensure Word references in Outlook were included). In the code below, I can get the address and other properties from each hyperlink embedded in the mail message, but not the human readable text that describes the name of the file the hyperlink references.

```vb
Public Sub SaveLinks()

Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim objMaildocument As Word.Document
Dim objHyperlink As Word.Hyperlink

' Initiate an Outlook Application object.
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

' Get the collection of selected objects.
Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

If objSelection.Count > 0 Then

    For Each objMail In objSelection
        Set objMaildocument = objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
        If objMaildocument.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
            For Each objHyperlink In objMaildocument.Hyperlinks
                MsgBox (objHyperlink.Address)
                MsgBox (objHyperlink.Name)
                MsgBox (objHyperlink.TextToDisplay)
            Next
        End If
    Next
End If

ExitSub:

Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objHyperlink = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing

End Sub
```

For a mail with links I get the web address address, and other properties of the hyperlink, but the `TexttoDisplay` property is always blank. I expect the text returned to be the text embedded in the email.

If I try to assign the property a value, I get Runtime error '4198' Command Failed, despite the documentation indicating that the property is read/Write.

Comment: Try `objHyperlink.Range.Text`

Comment: Perfect - Thanks!

That works flawlessly.

Comment: Left with the thought - should .TextToDisplay give me the human readable ? Is this a bug that I should report to MS?

Comment: The body of an email isn't originally a Word document (could have originally been plain text, rich text, or HTML for example) so maybe the `TextToDisplay` property isn't populated when a `Document` object is created from an email this way?